# How do I communicate with my Raspberry Pi from my computer using a c# service

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I want to work on a project where I control a led strip via a Raspberry Pi Zero when I change my wallpaper on my computer.

The current setup I've come up with will have a c# written service running on my computer and detecting when I change my wallpaper. This service will collect some data about the wallpaper and have to send me 3 color codes from my Raspberry Pi 3 to my Raspberry Pi Zero. Here is a scheme (sort of):

*Screen + Computer* >> **[LAN connection]** << *Raspberry Pi 3* >> [Bluetooth] < *Raspberry Pi Zero* >> *Led strip*

The question now is, how do I send the data from my computer to my Raspberry Pi 3?

I've did some reading and found out sockets could help me with this, but I honestly know nothing about this yet, so some references would be great.

Sidenote: I'm using Windows 10 IoT on my Raspberry Pi's, so it'll be all C# coding.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi is a full-scale computer on it's own -- unlike a microcontroller (e.g. an Arduino). Probably the simplest way to communicate is to run a web server *on the Pi* and interact with that using web calls from your PC (i.e. make a HTTP / REST call when your desktop changes).
Here's a stackexchange thread on the subject: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32380/windows-10-iot-on-rpi2-as-a-small-http-rest-web-api-server

Autohotkey might be worth looking at for making those triggered calls, but it can also be done with C#.
There is a question about detecting Wallpaper changes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5729603/423033

Comment: So you mean sending data to a web api hosted on my pi? Sounds pretty good to me!

Comment: And you mean using Autohotkey for detecting when my wallpaper changes?

Comment: Yes, it should be quite simple to host a Web API on Windows IoT. Question edited to add details.